# Why would iPhone ask 'allow "Settings" to use wireless data'?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, cellular-data

There is new iPhone 12, and when lauching any app first time, it asks many questions.

But why would iPhone ask for 'allow "Settings" to use wireless data'?

I don't think device configuration ("Settings") should be dependent on anything external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings themselves don't synchronise to iCloud, but the Settings app still accesses information from the Internet.

For the front page of Settings, this includes

- your account name and photo shown right at the top of the Settings app, and
- any account alerts such as whether your iCloud storage is full.

Going deeper into Settings presents lots of information from the Internet, such as

- information about software updates,
- a summary of iCloud storage space,
- Screen Time information from your other devices, and
- Game Center profile.

This is all information downloaded from the Internet, so network access is required. This is not an exhaustive list, but meant to demonstrate how a variety of information in the Settings app needs Internet access.

Comment: Thanks for a much clearer answer. I phoned in mine 